# Can anyone explain the function of this op-amp in a Velleman Clap On/Off Switch?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog

I am currently working on this project for a clap on/off switch by Velleman (MK139). I am trying to analyze this circuit and I noticed one thing. In the circuit diagram for this device, you can see the op-amp component IC1C at the midsection of the diagram. What I am trying to figure out is why exactly this op-amp isolated with only a connection to ground?

[image: MK139 Circuit Diagram]

I have no possible idea other than that the entire midsection is an audio amplifier (please correct me if that's not accurate) that helps convert the sound waves from the mic to an electrical signal.

Thanks so much for anyone's advice or input!

Comment: it is unused ...

Comment: IC1 contains four opamps, but the circuit only needs three.  It is generally recommended that unused opamps be connected as shown for IC1C.

Comment: @jstola haha yes, I did not realize that it was just a single IC that had multiple op-amps.. I just figured that if it was unused then it would merely just be absent from the circuit diagram!

Comment: @josh that is why the labels are IC1A, IC1B, IC1C and IC1D .... since it is a schematic diagram, the individual components are shown separate .... if it was a wiring diagram then the IC would be shown as the whole package, and there would be a rats nest of wires for the grounds and the supply voltages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LM324 is an integrated circuit containing four operational amplifiers; this is a common arrangement for cost savings as it allows for less integrated circuits to be used on a board, and lower package costs (which can dwarf wafer fabrication costs in many cases).

Three operational amplifiers are needed for this design; a single quad-op-amp chip is easier and cheaper to use than a dual op amp and a single op amp. By leaving the pins connected as-is (output to inverting input, non-inverting input to ground), the unused op-amp is in a well-defined state where it is unlikely to oscillate, use high amounts of power, or interfere with the correct operation of the other op-amps on the chip.

There is further reading in [this tech note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa204a/sboa204a.pdf) from TI. In a single-supply-rail application such as this one, setup recommended by TI is to use a resistive divider to pull the non-inverting input somewhere between the rails:

[image]

However, the tech note goes further:

> If the implementation of extra resistors is undesirable, the non-inverting input can be connected to any reference voltage that is within the specified common mode and output ranges.This technique favors an op-amp with rail-to-rail input and/or output range characteristics.

Checking the datasheet for the LM324, the common-mode input range and output swing do indeed go all the way down to ground.

Comment: Hey dude thanks so much for the explanation!!!

Comment: Since you may see this, im hoping if I could ask you an additional question. Is that entire midsection of the circuit diagram used to produce an electrical current from the input received from the mic?

Comment: @josh I'd need to do some deeper analysis to give a solid answer. As far as I can tell at first glance, IC1A and surroundings are a filter, possibly high- or band-pass, IC1B and surroundings could be a peak or edge detector, and IC1D/surroundings look like a comparator with some positive feedback for hysteresis. I don't know what you mean by "produce an electrical current"; there are electrical currents flowing in a bunch of different spots in the circuit, and their waveforms vary differently as audio input is detected.

Comment: Haha I am going to be honest with you but I am thinking that my overall understanding of this circuit may be skewed. See, my overly simple view of this midsection at least is since the microphone is a transducer, it would produce an electrical analog output signal and as it flows through the series of op-amps, it would 'amplify' that electric signal from the mic and if it reaches a high enough threshold, will fire up the relay section of the circuit. Thanks for your explanation of all of the op-amps that is really helpful!!

Comment: @josh That's on the right track, but misses a key point -- op amps are very versatile devices beyond "just" amplifying. While they can be used to just amplify when used with a few resistors, in this case capacitors and diodes, as well as other elements, are used to do more "interesting" things like filtering and peak detection.

Comment: Interesting! Crazy how something that looks so simple has some cool things going on inside. I'll keep trying to analyze this thing! Thanks so much for all the input.